# Add params in strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Lets say I have params like this:

```
def boat_params
   params
      .require(:boat)
      .permit(:message
              :alarm_en,
              :alarm_es,
              :alarm_sv)
end
```

---

What I try is basically **shorten this code**, with:

```
def boat_params
   params
      .require(:boat)
      .permit(:message).merge(alarm_params)
end
```

But for `alarm_params` I get errors when **I tried**:

```
def alarm_params
    params = {}
    ["en","es","sv"].each do |lang|
       params << "alarm_#{lang}" 
    end
    return params
end
```

What raised the error:

```
undefined method `<<' for {}:Hash
```

for: `params << "alarm_#{lang}"`

---

**Next I tried it with an Array:**

```
def alarm_params
    params = []
    ["en","es","sv"].each do |lang|
       params << "alarm_#{lang}" 
    end
    return params
end
```

What raised the error:

```
 undefined method `to_hash'
```

In `.merge(alarm_params)`

**What do I wrong? Thanks!**

Comment: It looks like a bad refactoring to me. anyway try .permit(:message *alarm_params) and alarm_params being an array

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `merge` on the result of `permit`, which returns `ActionController::Parameters`, not a generic hash.

Since `permit` takes an array, you can actually just do the following:

```
def alarm_params
  %w{ alarm_en alarm_es alarm_sv }
end

def boat_params
  params.require(:boat).permit(:message, *alarm_params)
end
```

If you wanted to use metaprogramming to pull a list of languages and create the permitted params for each, as you're currently doing in `alarm_params`, you could do the following more readily:

```
def languages
  # possibly use a more global config var, or ENV
  # e.g. ENV['SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES']
  %w{ en es sv }
end

def alarm_params
  languages.map { |lang| "alarm_#{lang}" }
end
```

No need for `each`, or the explicit `return`.

Answer (score 1):

The argument to the permit is an array, not a hash. You can try to use the splat operator `*`

```
def boat_params
   params
      .require(:boat)
      .permit(:message, *alarm_params)
end
```